# Unable to Cast WebDriver Instance to JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium, casting, nullpointerexception

I'm running `WebDriver` (`Selenium`) & I'm attempting to cast `WebDriver driver` to `JavascriptExecutor` as follows:

```
Object aa = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", this.element);
```

However I either get a class cast exception or a null pointer exception when I run this code.

My situation is as follows: I've created a `WebDriverAdapter` class which accepts a concrete instance of `WebDriver` as follows:

```
private final WebDriver driver;

public WebDriverAdapter(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

I then created another class named `WebDriverDecorator` which accepts an instance of `WebDriverAdapter`. The class looks as follows:

```
WebDriverAdapter driver;


public WebDriverDecorator(WebDriverAdapter driver, ...)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    ....; // Random String parameter.
}
```

When I attempt to cast any of the Drivers to JS executor I get a `class cast exception`.

On the other hand if I have both `WebDriverAdapter` and `WebDriverDecorator`  extend `RemoteWebDriver` I do *not* get a class cast exception but I *do* get a `NullPointerException`.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

**Edit:** In `Main` my program looks like this:

```
WebDriver FFDriver = new FirefoxDriver();   
WebDriverAdapter driverAdapter = new WebDriverAdapter(FFDriver);
WebDriverDecorator driverDecorator = new  WebDriverDecorator(driverAdapter, "....");

driverDecorator.navigate().to("http://google.com"); // Works correctly



String XPath = ("//*[@id='gbw']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a");

WebElement e1 = driver.findElementByXPath(.....);



System.out.println(e1.getText()); // Works correctly


Object aa = ((JavascriptExecutor)driverDecorator).executeScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", e1); // Causes NullPointerException or Class cast exception depending on if I extend remote web driver or not..
```

Comment: Give also the code of WebDriverDecorator class.

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was working on this for some time and found the solution. Since no one answered the question I'll post the answer I came up with.

Basically, all I needed to do was add `implements JavascriptExecutor` to both `WebDriverDecorator` and `WebDriverAdapter` and add unimplemented methods (such as  `executeScript(String arg0, Object... arg1)` ). I would then cast each respective driver to `JS executor` inside the unimplemented method and now I'm able to call `executeScript()` directly on driver of `WebDriverDecorator` or `WebDriverAdapter` without casting anything.